# What is the source code of a typical pre-built Nagios Plugin like (check_load)?

Tags: java, bash, shell, nagios

I want to build a few Nagios plugins of my own and wanted to check out how the existing plugins work.

I downloaded a sample plugin check_load. But I am not able to open it with any text editor.
What is the file extension?

Can a plugin be a simple shell script which executes a jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. It can be a shell script, an executable, pretty much anything. Nagios plugins are just "things" which produce output on the standard output which is compliant with the format that Nagios expects from the plug-ins.

You probably want to read some of this : http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html

Comment: What is check_load written in?

Comment: It's written in C. You can check the source yourself : http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagiosplug/files/